# airport express reverse connection

Tags: network, wifi, airport

One way to use airport express (yes I'm talking about that apple router) is to replace our home wifi router with it.

It can be used in a different way also (kinda like an wifi adapter ), which I call reverse mode. In which I make it connect wirelessly to my home wireless and I plug its cable in a computer in which I want to have internet. This computer do not have wifi adapter, so I'm using airport express kinda like an wifi adapter. I'm running Linux on this computer but to my understanding it works the same way for macOS/Windows.

This way I can access internet normally on my Linux box. However I cannot ping other computers in the network which are connected directly to my home wifi router, why?

Other computer in the network also cannot ping the computer connected to airport express.

Looks like what I'm doing is called `Wirelessly Extended Network (802.11n)` on [support.apple.com/en-us/HT202056](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202056). I would like to have that computer being able to ping others in the network, but it looks like the computer is kinda hidden behind the airport, would this be possible? And I want that computer on same network range as others.

Comment: Do you mean bridge mode as explained in https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202056 ?

Comment: Updated question considering your comment. Now wondering if that WDS mode would help me someway?